# Preempt a state doesn't work

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have tried to do a concurrence state with one one monitor-state that check for a reset topic and one state with a lot of sub-states that do the actual work. The goal is to and the work if someone publish on the reset topic. My problem is that then I publish and the monitor-state get active and try to preempt the other state nothing happen and the work continue:

For every sub state it said:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1480428562.104071] [3378.814000] Preempt requested on state machine before executing the next state. 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1480428562.105243] [3378.814000] Last state 'First task' did not service preempt. Preempting next state 'Second task' before executing...
```

But then continue. Do I have to add something to all the state that should happend then preempting? They are ordinary smach.state.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249038/preempt-a-state-doesn%27t-work/) by [pv](https://answers.ros.org/users/28200/pv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> > Last state 'First task'  did not service preempt

indicates that the state was requested to preempt but did not respond to it. If 'First task' is a homemade smach.state, then you need to implement what do to when preempt is requested. Look at the interface for smach.state: preempt_requested and service_preempt.

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0